# Jquery : How to prevent prefix addition to address within an `<a>` Tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a HTML `<a>` Tag as follows:

```
<a id="ext_link" href="www.google.com">GOOGLE HOME</a>
```

And I am using JQUERY to open link in a new window. The JQUERY is as below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ext_link").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        window.open($(this).attr("href"));
    });
});
```

When I use `<a id="ext_link" href="http"//www.google.com">GOOGLE HOME</a>` it works fine, but when I use `<a id="ext_link" href="www.google.com">GOOGLE HOME</a>` a new window opens and the addressbar contains `http://localhost/app/www.google.com` which is wrong address obviously...

How can I prevent the automatic addition of `http://localhost/app/` at the beginning.

Comment: You have to provide the `http://` (or whatever protocol it is), otherwise it's interpreted as a relative link.

Comment: while giving url in href you should give the full url including `http` ot `https`

Comment: Check if string begins with `http(s)?://` if not add it.

Comment: try `href="//www.google.com"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to test if your `href` start with `http://` or `https://`, if not then add `http://`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ext_link").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        if(!/^(http|https):\/\//.test(url)){
            url = "http://" + url;
        }
        window.open(url);
    });
});
```

Comment: What about links that already have `http://` and gets `http://http://www.google.com`?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the href doesn't contain the http:// and add it like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ext_link").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        if(!/^https?:\/\//.test(url)){
            url = "http://" + url;
        }
        window.open(url);
    });
});
```

You can add more protocols but `https?://` should be enough. Or you could just use `//` as many modern browsers use it and gets the appropriate protocol.