# safeHtml after sanitizing html content (sometimes with a tags) redirect url to localhost+site from href

Tags: angular7, sanitize

I saw, and checked some other topics about sanitizing html and url on angular site by pipe etc..

That's fine if we have some html or url as a separate variable/code, but how can I deal with let say some content with included a tags?

I tried html file with:

```
<div class="text-description" [innerHTML]="meeting.description | extendedSafeHtml:'url' | extendedSafeHtml: 'html'">
```

and the pipe with code:

```
transform(value: any, type: string): SafeHtml | SafeStyle | SafeScript | SafeUrl | SafeResourceUrl {
        switch (type) {
            case 'html': return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
            case 'style': return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value);
            case 'script': return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustScript(value);
            case 'url': return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
            case 'resourceUrl': return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
            default: throw new Error(`Invalid safe type specified: ${type}`);
        }
    }
```

meeting.description is a string:

```
<p><strong>Hello,</strong></p>
<p><br></p>
<p>Join our meeting. Visit our website <a href="www.site.com">www.site.com</a> &amp; <a href="www.facebook.com">www.facebook.com</a></p>
<p><br></p>
```

Result is when I click a tag then I'm redirected to localhost:4200/www.site.com

Expected result: Angular doesn't add any prefix before address in href

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

ah... after some deeper research about DomSanitizer I end up with the knowledge that it only changes malicious code, so if a tag doesn't have it then it will leave it as it is. After that, I started looking for topics why there is that unwanted prefix, and that link helped me:
[jquery-how-to-prevent-prefix-addition-to-address-within-an-a-tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22370481/jquery-how-to-prevent-prefix-addition-to-address-within-an-a-tag)
so generally it was enough to just use HTTPS protocol with a href element otherwise the path is treated as a relevant path

I hope it will help someone and you don't waste as much time as I wasted.